# Set listener instance in fragment on application restore

Tags: android, android-fragments, listener

I have created ErrorDialogFragment which contains OnDialogClickListener parameter.

Every other Fragment or Activity that needs to show ErrorDialogFragment sets OnDialogClickListener via public method in ErrorDialogFragment. In the same time, all those activities and fragments implements OnDialogClickListener .

Problem occurs if user exits from application when ErrorDialogFragment is showed, and returns after a while (app is removed from memory). If user clicks on fragment options it will force close, because OnDialogClickListener is not set.

Am i wrong with with activity-listener-fragment pattern, and how do i solve this (application is in beta already.. big pattern change is not acceptable.

Eg:

Interface:

```
public interface OnDialogClickListener {
    public void OnPositiveClick(int key, Object... args);
    public void OnNegativeClick(int key, Object... args);
}
```

Activity:

```
public class Home extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener, ServiceConnection, OnDialogClickListener {
    .
    .
    .
@Override
public void OnPositiveClick(int key, Object... args) {
    //some actions
}

@Override
public void OnNegativeClick(int key, Object... args) {
    //some actions
}
```

Fragment:

```
public class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener {

OnDialogClickListener OnDialogClickListener = null;

    .
    .
    .

public void setDialogListener(OnDialogClickListener listener)
{   
    OnDialogClickListener = listener;
}

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {    
    if(OnDialogClickListener != null){
        switch (which) {
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                this.dismiss();
                OnDialogClickListener.OnPositiveClick(KEY, args);
                break;
            default:
                this.dismiss();
                OnDialogClickListener.OnNegativeClick(KEY, args);
                break;
        }
    }
    else
        this.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're way off better setting it in `DialogFragment#onAttach(Activity)` callback like this:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try { 
        mOnDialogClickListener = (OnDialogClickListener) activity;
    } catch(ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + "must implement" + OnDialogClickListener.class.getSimpleName());
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach()
    mOnDialogClickListener = null;
}
```

And finally, obviously, make your `Activity` implements `OnDialogClickListener`

Comment: This is just another way of setting listener but it wont set my listener again, when app is returning from paused state, because, in fragment lifecycle, OnAttach is called only once, when fragment is initially created.

Comment: have you tried it yet? this is my implementation on every project and always works

Answer (score 0):

Just write `this.dismiss()` after `OnDialogClickListener()` callback.

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {    
    if(OnDialogClickListener != null){
        switch (which) {
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:

                OnDialogClickListener.OnPositiveClick(KEY, args);
                this.dismiss();
                break;
            default:

                OnDialogClickListener.OnNegativeClick(KEY, args);
                this.dismiss();
                break;
        }
    }
    else
        this.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: I although, what you wrote makes sense, but i think you misinterpret my question. If application goes to pause state when ErrorDialog is shown and then user restores app (when app is cleared from memory) OnDialogListener is null (as all other properties ofcourse, but all other properties are set from savedInstanceState)

Answer (score 0):

In all your onResume() methods of your Activities and Fragments, that implement OnDialogClickListener, you have to to make sure to get a hold of your DialogFragment instance and reset the listener of it.

You can get the reference from the FragmentManager.findFragmentByXyz() or by FragmentManager.getFragments()
Note, that on Compatibility Package V13 there is no FragmentManager.getFragments() (yet?! who knows...).

Comment: This might work. Its just i see ugliness with this approach. What if i have 20 different dialog fragments. 20 different instances to reset listener reference.
Although this might work with reflection usage. Iterating through <? extends DialogFragment> classes and setting listener property of each class (fragment). What do you think?

Comment: Please don't use instanceof cascades, instead set some arguments inside your Fragments when creating it (all arguments will be recreated in the life cycle) and check those arguments. So you have something like if (StringUtils.equals(Fragment.getArguments().getString("purpose"), "Edit name")) { //do stuff }

Comment: I don't know why you would need 20 different Fragments simultaneously inside your FragmentManager, but if you literally have so many Fragmemts with complex dependencies between one another and other components like Activity, then you could think about tying it together nicely inside a central EventObserverDispatcher of some sort, so that Fragments, etc. that are interested in certain events, can register for it and will be notified when the event  of the subject occurrs. You could put this event dispatcher inside the life cycle of your parent Activity (wich can also...

Comment: ....register for it and will be notified). You could access it by `((EventDispatcherProvider) Fragment.getActivity()).register(Fragment.this, EventId.DialogNameEdit);`