# How to not close AlertDialog android

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

Hi my problem is when I select an item my `AlertDialog` dismiss

```
alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
alertDialog
        .setSingleChoiceItems(ageArr, 1, btnSelectItem)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok, btnPositiveAgeDialog)
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_cancel, null)
        .show();
```

what my dialog click positive looks is.

```
private DialogInterface.OnClickListener btnSelectItem = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        selectedIndexAge = which;
    }
};
```

I tried setting the listener to null and it does not close but still
I needed it because I wanted to know which item is selected

Comment: @Ibrahim that's totally different..

Comment: You're saying that when you choose one of the items in your `ageArr` single-choice list, the dialog automatically closes? I checked the documentation for both `android.app.AlertDialog.Builder` and the support library version, and they both include statements like "The dialog will not be dismissed when an item is clicked. It will only be dismissed if clicked on a button"

Comment: @BenP. yes sir. It dismisses whenever I choose an item in the alert dialog

I mean not just when I click that ok or cancel also when I click or select an item

Comment: @BenP. Yes it's not only on the buttons. According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#DismissingADialog) `The system also dismisses the dialog when the user touches an item in a dialog list, except when the list uses radio buttons or checkboxes.`

Comment: @Beginner Why do you want the dialog to NOT be dismissed?

Comment: @Eselfar I use the dialog for updating the age and I only update the age when the user click ok button the problem is when user select an age item the dialog automatically closes which is not the right specs, I know I can solve it using custom dialog fragment but as for now my goal is to achieve it on just non custom dialog

Comment: @Beginner You can use [this library](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs). It let you add a custom layout in the dialog AND you can choose the dialog to be dismissed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just put it

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(null);
```

or

You can use the implementation of hasOnClickListeners() for knowing the status of listener taken from android.view.View class for

```
 public boolean hasOnClickListeners() {
        ListenerInfo li = mListenerInfo;
        return (li == null && li.mOnClickListener == null);
    }
```

Use the following link for further modifications

[Set listener instance in fragment on application restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218729/set-listener-instance-in-fragment-on-application-restore)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
  {            
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v)
      {
          Boolean wantToCloseDialog = false;
          //Do stuff, possibly set wantToCloseDialog to true then...
          if(wantToCloseDialog)
              dialog.dismiss();
          //else dialog stays open. Make sure you have an obvious way to close the dialog especially if you set cancellable to false.
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Something else must be closing your `AlertDialog`. Below is a program that I believe duplicates the minimum requirements you have posted, and selecting one of the items does not close the dialog.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] values = new String[]{ "one", "two", "three", "four" };

        DialogInterface.OnClickListener choiceListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "selected index: " + which, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "positive button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setSingleChoiceItems(values, 1, choiceListener)
                .setPositiveButton("ok", positiveListener)
                .setNegativeButton("cancel", null)
                .show();
    }
}
```